# Change indentation in Sass

Tags: ruby, sass

How can I change indentation from 2 spaces to 4 spaces in output CSS files when using Sass? I'm using expanded style. I don't know anything about Ruby, but I have tried to read every rb file in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.1/` on my computer.

Comment: I've asked myself the same question and haven't found an answer so far. I'm curious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/tree/visitors/to_css.rb` has a number of hard-coded double-space strings (`'  '`) that are used for indentation. If you replace them all with four-space strings it will compile your css as you stated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not working for me. Actually this was first thing I tried. Indentation stays on 2 spaces.

Comment: How are you compiling your sass files?

Comment: Im compiling sass files through terminal on mac, using command "watch". Answer was actually correct, but I had to update my Sass to sass-3.2.3. Now indentations works perfectly! Thank you very-very-very much Zach! :)

Answer (score 1):

The right way to change the sass indenting is to go to `rubygems/gems/sass-3.x.x/lib/sass/tree/visitors/to_css.rb` (or anywhere your to_css.rb file is), and edit this:

`tab_str = '  ' * (@tabs + node.tabs)`

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the referenced question regarding `sass` indentation and as of now (DEC 2019), the accepted answer is outdated; I add this answer.
According to [`sass` documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api#indenttype), amongst its options, it accepts two options called `indentType` and `indentWidth` to control indentation behavior.
The default is using 4 spaces which can be changed to 1 tab like this:

```
function css() {
    return gulp
    .src("./scss/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: "expanded",
        includePaths: "./node_modules",
        indentType: "tab",
        indentWidth: 1
    }))
    .on("error", sass.logError)
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(header(banner, {
        pkg: pkg
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./css"))
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix: ".min"
    }))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./css"))
    .pipe(browsersync.stream());
}
```