# Custom Indentation Type for SASS Output

Tags: ruby, sass, indentation, foreman

My team is working with a vendor who prefers a 4-space hard tab to the 2-space soft tab that comes with the SASS expanded output style (I know, I know - we tried to talk them into the two-space deal, but they won't budge). We use [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) to handle all of our compiling, so we don't have surface-level access to the sass-convert command that lets you set the indent-style during compilation.

I'm familiar with being able to change the 4 different output styles for SASS, and I know that you can change the tab style on your local environment like in [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689264/change-indentation-in-sass), but I was wondering if there's a way to do this automatically through the config.rb file where we set the output style to start with.

Comment: If Sass doesn't output the indentation style you're looking for, you have to make a modification to Sass itself (which is what the linked SO question shows), and you have to make sure every machine that's compiling Sass has your custom Sass installed.

Comment: Thanks, cimmanon - I understand that you can do it on a per-user basis like that, but I don't know if that is a good solution given the size of the team working on the issue. I was trying to find out if anyone knows of a system-wide answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as "4-space hard tabs". A hard tab is just a character.

It is editor settings that decide how wide a tab should be displayed. You can set it to be two, four, eight spaces wide, and it will not alter the source code.

The matter is that **SASS does support tabs for indentation**, with one tab meaning one level of indentation. So there should be no problem for you.

If you're talking about the indentation of CSS files, i really don't understand why this is of any significance for your team. If you're using SASS, CSS files are not supposed to be edited and are rarely ever opened (most debugging takes place in developer tools like FireBug, are you aware of [debug_info and source maps](http://snugug.com/musings/debugging-sass-source-maps)?). In production CSS is minified and all white space is purged.

Consider adopting a task runner tool like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). You can leverage it to parse resulting CSS files at certain stage of the development routine cycle. You can also make use of the brilliant [autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer) tool if you go this way.

PS Two spaces is the standard indentation for the Ruby community, which SASS is mostly a part of. You team is kinda stemming the tide.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The situation we're in has various levels of ridiculousness, one of which is that our team writes using SASS, but the people that we're working with only want to use the compiled CSS. My team is all for using the two-space, we're just trying to comply with our client's request for a hard tab.

Right now we're compiling the SASS using compass watch. I was trying to work with sass-convert for a minute, then I realized that it won't work for CSS-to-CSS. The Grunt option sounds like a good choice - I'll explore that route.

Comment: How are you combining editing SASS with editing CSS? Whenever you edit SASS, the changes in CSS are overwritten!

Comment: We're just making a style guide for them that they're taking the compiled css from to use on a project.

Comment: Makes sense. Well, try leveraging Grunt with a custom script to replace spaces to tabs after SASS compilation. Also have a look at [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) (here's an [installation guide](http://decodize.com/css/installing-yeoman-front-end-development-stack-windows/) for Windows).