# Indentation with tab character in SASS output

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to have sass output with tabs instead of spaces?

I know there is the classic argument of spaces but I have a requirement that all my css needs to be indented with tabs before checked in to source control.

Any ideas?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218315/custom-indentation-type-for-sass-output

Comment: Why do you have a requirement for generated code? Your SASS is your source code, your css is generated. If you were to use a third party CSS library (such as twitter's bootstrap) you wouldn't go through and reformat it to your specs.

Comment: The general recommendation is that generated CSS should not be within version control, only the source files necessary to create it.

Comment: @Mike not helpful. I don't make the specs my client does. Not going to argue that it is ridiculous.

Comment: @manishie: I don't see an answer in that post. It says it is possible but doesn't explain how. Did I miss something? It recommended using Grunt but that is not my question. I don't want to use Grunt.

Comment: That's pretty typical of answers from lolmaus.  You should be able to just use a simple search/replace script on the generated file.  The only instance of 2 spaces should be from indentation, since Sass normalizes all whitespace on output.

Comment: I don't understand why people question coding style. There are plenty of reasons why people have different coding styles. Some reasons are bad, but not worth losing a job over. Generated output is not excluded from such considerations. E.g. I'm trying to move over to SASS now but all our old CSS is tab-indented. Changing to Ruby's guidleines makes for a lot of unnecessary Git commits, and in some cases merge conflicts. @cimmanon If generated content is not also tracked in Git, it doesn't make it into exports from `git-archive`, don't presume your needs are the same as everyone else's.

Comment: Don't make assumptions.  I personally store my compiled CSS files in version control, knowing full well that the recommendation is that you not do that.  Other types of projects that are compiled typically do not track the executable in version control either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by manishie (and his link), there's not built-in way to change how the outputted CSS is indented. The only way is to run it through a separate tool (like Grunt) to "correct" the indentation as you see fit.