# Sass Error: Invalid CSS after "...0, 0, -5deg); }": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "{"

Tags: css, sass, compilation

Sass error throwed when compile this:

```
@keyframes flipInX

    from
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg)
        animation-timing-function: ease-in
        opacity: 0

    40%
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg)
        animation-timing-function: ease-in

    60%
        opacity: 1
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg)

    80%
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg)

    to
        transform: perspective(400px)
```

The error points to this line:

```
    ...
80%
```

> transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg)

```
to
    ...
```

This error was throwed in past in different places and disappeared after switching lines or retyping tabs and/or new line typing. This seems like a bug and this is very annoying. How i can fix this?

P.S. I am working in Sublime Text 3 if it can help...

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like it is your **indentation**.
Sass has a indented syntax – indentation is equal to using `{}`.

In your example the indentation is missing, so the code cannot be compiled correctly.

Copying your code into a CodePen and giving it indentation is fixing the error for me:

```
@keyframes flipInX
  from
      transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg)
      animation-timing-function: ease-in
      opacity: 0
  40%
      transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg)
      animation-timing-function: ease-in      
  60%
      opacity: 1
      transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg)
  80%
      transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg)
  to
      transform: perspective(400px)
```

**An indentation is made of two spaces, no tabs.**

Comment: Yes, copying to codepen and giving it indentation fixed problem. Codepen uses 2 spaces per tab. I retype tabs in my editor for 4-spaces per tab indent and it works, but the problem still exists... Maybe the editor causes problems with identation. How to fix it - is the question

Comment: In the Sass Guidelines (https://sass-guidelin.es/) it says that Sass needs an indentation of two spaces.
https://codepen.io/Sixl/pen/vvGLvx?editors=1101
Can you explain your remark 'I retype tabs in my editor for 4-spaces per tab'?

Comment: There are also answers on how to change indentation (2 spaces to 4 spaces) for Sass on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689264/change-indentation-in-sass

Comment: @DanielSixl in Sublime you can tell it to use tabs or spaces when you indent. You can also tell it how many spaces are in an indent. I believe this is what the OP is talking about.

Comment: 'I retype tabs in my editor for 4-spaces per tab' means - i replace 2-space tabs with 4-space tabs. Thanks for links. And i see also - when i open sass file with wordpad, i see 3-space tabs and missing tabs and idk why sublime shows this different then it is in file... I try Visual Code Editor and Notpad++ and they show file like Sublime...

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem i find here: [How do I force Sublime Text to indent two spaces per tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474090/how-do-i-force-sublime-text-to-indent-two-spaces-per-tab/9474136)

The problem was in incorrect indentation in my editor (Thanks to [Daniel Sixl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7233016/daniel-sixl)). Changing preferences in Sublime Text solves the problem (i hope it will never appear again). The preferences is:

```
"tab_size": 2,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
"detect_indentation": false,
```

Comment: Sidenote: There is a shortcut in Sublime Text, if needed indentation changes often: Just click on the bottom right info message about current indentation of document. A context menu will appear with all choices.